# How to update multiple mongo collections inside the same function in spring webflux?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux

There are 2 collections in my mongoDB:
  1.**users** collection which contains user phone number and wwhether it is verified or not?

```
{
   _id: '12123',
   phones: [ 
      {
         phoneNumber: '1234567890',
         verified: false
      }
   ]
}
```

2. **verificationTokens** collection which contains the verification code mapped by id from user collection as **userId**.

```
{
   _id: '1111',
   userId: '12123',
   token: '4545'
}
```

I'm creating an endpoint in Spring WebFlux to verify the phone number. The endpoint receives the **userId** and **verificationCode**. If the token in the collection matches the token sent by the user, then update the verified to true in user collection.

I'm trying to write a single function that would be called by this endpoint and make the required changes.

I tried in the following code but the verified status is not updating to true.

```
   public Mono<VerifyPhoneToken> verifyPhoneNumber(String id, String verificationCode) {
        return verifyPhoneTokensRepository.findByUserId(id)
                .flatMap(vpt -> {
                    if (verificationCode.equals(vpt.getToken())) {
                        usersRepository.findById(id)
                                .flatMap(user -> {
                                    user.getPhones().get(0).setVerified(true);
                                    return usersRepository.save(user);
                                });
                        return verifyPhoneTokensRepository.save(vpt);
                    }
                    return null;
                });
    }
```

Also, I would like to know if `return null` can be handled in a better way.

Comment: You shouldnt return null, you should return a mono.empty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im guessing your problem is when you are calling the `usersRepository` you are not handling the return thus breaking the event chain. You should try something like:

```
public Mono<VerifyPhoneToken> verifyPhoneNumber(String id, String verificationCode) {
    return verifyPhoneTokensRepository.findByUserId(id)
            .flatMap(vpt -> {
                if (verificationCode.equals(vpt.getToken())) {
                    return updateUser(id)
                            .then(verifyPhoneTokensRepository.save(vpt));
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            });
}

private Mono<User> updateUser(String id) {
    return usersRepository.findById(id)
            .flatMap(user -> {
                user.getPhones().get(0).setVerified(true);
                return usersRepository.save(user);
            });
}
```

using `then` to chain on your action. Also dont return `null` return `Mono<Void>` (Mono.empty())